# MySQL output one below the other

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, pdo

In my database the Information is saved like this:

```
Football  ART-NR-1337 Price: 5$
Basketball ART-NR-1333 Price: 10$
```

Now I want to create a .php file that shows me the article like this:

> ```
> Football     Basketball
> ART-NR-1337  ART-NR-1333
> Price: 5$    Price: 10$
> ```

Not like this, this isn't what I got but I didn't need this.

```
Football  ART-NR-1337 Price: 5$
```

Comment: Not sure why you would want to do this anyway, just format the data in php. but its certainly a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

I got it

```
foreach($database->query($sql) as $row)             
                        {
                            echo '<tr>';
                            foreach($database->query($sql) as $row){
                                echo '<td>'.utf8_encode($row["Heldt"]).'</td>';
                            }
                            echo '</tr>';
                        }
```